# Using dict[str, T] in T (TypeVar)

Tags: python, json

I would like to point out that T (of type TypeVar) must have dict[str, T] that this does not work.

I tried:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', dict[str, 'T'], list['T'], str, float, int, bool, type(None))
```

where T represents valid types for JSON.

But type checking says:

```
TypeVar constraint type cannot be generic
```

Comment: What is your question? Please take a moment to read [ask] for tips on asking a question that will attract the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Could you explain what you want `T` to represent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add extra information (as I've done now); no need to post additional info in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you didn't specify the dict and the list:

my python is 3.10.11
the code :

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', dict, list, str, float, int, bool, type(None))
```

and it worked fine, try it that way

Comment: I already tried but it does not work we can assign dict[str, tuple] which is not supported for the `json` module.

Comment: so you want to add a json type in the T variable !